# iOS - how to load hundreds of pictures in rich text editor, which in form of UIWebView or UItextView

Tags: ios, image, optimization, heap-memory, rich-text-editor

I want to load a lot of pictures in my editor,but as it loads the memory always keep increasing. the more pictures loaded in the editor, the more memory it takes.

Is there any idea like the tableView, to release the memory of pictures when they are invisible, and load again when visible. I cannot find any solution in UIWebView or UITextView.

P.S. I'm trying to load the pictures in form of JavaScript in UIWebView.
 and I also try to load the pictures in form of NSAttributeString(NStextAttachment).

Answer (score 0):

Just #import the UIImageView+WebCache.h header, and call the sd_setImageWithURL:placeholderImage: method from the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: UITableViewDataSource method. Everything will be handled for you, from async downloads to caching management.

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Import this library

```
[cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
                      placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Comment: We can say that lazy Loading

Comment: thanks for your advice. But the problem I face is actually dealing with pictures in a rich text editor, so it's not suitable to use UITableView for that.

Comment: To use a editor to type in text and inset image, seems I can only set a editable UIWebView or UITextView in the ViewController. If I use the tableView that means I have to divide the editing text into many piece and put in different cells....